# How do I stop AI movement with OnTriggerEnter2D in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a basic AI script for my enemies in Unity and I have most of it working the way I want it to. The way I have my enemies set up they contain 2 colliders, a polygon collider that destroys the player when touched, and an empty game object that's a child of the enemy that is a circle collider that acts as a trigger. There's a game object that's tagged `Straight Road` and when the circle collider comes in contact with it, it should run a function called `StopMovement();` that sets the enemies movement to 0. I used to `Debug.Log();` to check to see if the collider recognizes that it's touching `Straight Road` and it doesn't. This is my code below. I'm hoping someone has a suggestion.

```
public class DogAI : GenericController {

    public Transform target;
    public float chaseRange;
    public float maxDistance;

    private Vector3 targetDirection;
    private float targetDistance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        if (target.transform != null)
        {
            targetDirection = target.transform.position - transform.position;
            targetDirection = targetDirection.normalized;
            targetDistance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

            if (targetDistance <= chaseRange)
            {
               SetMovement(targetDirection);
            }

            Vector3 enemyScreenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

            if (targetDistance > maxDistance)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    void StopMovement()
    {
        SetMovement(new Vector2(0,0));
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Straight Road"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Stop! There's a road!");//This never shows up in the log?
            StopMovement();
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            DestroyObject(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Generic Controller script below containing the `SetMovement()` function.

```
public abstract class GenericController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed = 20;
    float animationSpeed = 1;

    protected Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    protected Animator animator;

    Vector2 movementVector;
    float currentSpeed;

    protected bool needAnimator = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    protected void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (needAnimator)
        {
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            animator.speed = animationSpeed;
        }
    }


    protected void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = movementVector;
        currentSpeed = rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;

        if (needAnimator)
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", currentSpeed);
    }

    public void SetMovement(Vector2 input)
    {
        movementVector = input * movementSpeed;
    }

    public void SetMovement(int x, int y)
    {
        SetMovement(new Vector2(x, y));
    }
```

Comment: Did you try printing other.gameObject.tag? Incase its a prefab or something, there might be a name difference. Like "Straight Road(Clone)" or something of that sort

Comment: No it's not that. I placed a road in the scene for testing so that wouldn't happen. I just recently figured out why the debug wasn't showing in the console though. I ended up attaching a `2D Box Collider` to the road. It shows the debug, but it still doesn't run `StopMovement()`

Comment: can you share the setmovement code？ might as well have look in there and any other place where movement code is attached? also did you check if your code runs in update after you said stop movement? i can see `if (target.transform != null)` will still be there if you did not made **target.transform = null** which might also result in overriding your stopmovement in update

Comment: I can add the `SetMovement` code. It's in a separate class another guy in my team created. I have `if (target.transform != null)` in there to just make sure we didn't mistakenly forget to add the player into the scene. Not sure if that is or isn't part of the issue though.

Comment: Why `CompareTag`? Shouldn't it be `other.gameObject.tag`?

Comment: I just tired changing that and it didn't work. I'm still fairly new to Unity. I'm not sure what difference is between `other.gameObject.ComapreTag("thing")` and `other.gameObject.tag == "thing"`. Is there an advantage or a specific time to one over the other?

Comment: Try adding logs to `StopMovement()` before and after `SetMovement()` line. See the results. Probably you need to make a reference from GenericController to DogAI . Your code style is different than mine so it's a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Looks like you are resetting SetMovement on every Update. This is likely overriding your StopMovement. Perhaps you want to check if your movement is 0 before attempting to execute SetMovement in your Update function.  Or perhaps you want to create a new function on your class and have it set movementSpeed. This way you could set movementSpeed to 0 and it wouldn't make any different what its direction  is set to. Also, another option would be to create a setTarget function so you could set the target to null and thus skip your movement logic all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html):

> **MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)**
>
> Sent when another object enters a trigger collider attached to this object (2D physics only).

The keyword here is **enters**. In other words, a trigger is for when something goes **inside** the area of the collider, like a player entering a region of the map, where the region is a trigger collider. If you want something to happen when a collider **collides** with the road, i.e. when your `CircleCollider` comes in contact with the road, then you want the collider to not be a trigger, and you want the functionality to be inside [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).